# Core Audio code running on simulator mutes currently playing audio

Tags: macos, core-audio

Every time I'm working on a Core Audio application, specifically one that utilizes real-time audio via the `remoteIO` audio unit render callbacks, the moment I start the audio unit engine running whatever music I am playing via youtube or itunes is muted.  I must reload the youtube page or reset my system preference audio settings to get sound back.  Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the mix-with-others property on the Simulator's RemoteIO Audio Unit before starting it.  Also enable a proper AVAudioSession category.

Comment: I see no method within the AVAudioSession API that lets me set a `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers` option.  I tried setting it using the deprecated AudioSessionSet* functions but it still shut down my other running audio apps.

Comment: See options for AVAudioSession:setCategory:withOptions:error: